# Cucumber- // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I Tried to execute the same test with different data but I am getting the following error when I tried to run the test

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@When("^Enter the ADMIN and password(\\d+)$") 

public void enter_the_ADMIN_and_password(int arg1) throws Throwable {

// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
throw new PendingException();

}
```

Below is my Feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Login 
Given Open chrome and login
When Enter the <Username> and <Password>
Then Click on Login
Examples: 
|Username           |Password   | 
|ADMIN              |password123|
```

Below is the @when annotation part in Steps file

```
@When("^Enter the \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")                  
    public void enter_the_Username_and_Password(String username,String Password) throws Throwable                           
    {       
       System.out.println("This step enter the Username and Password on the login page."+username +Password);
       loginObj.Login(driver);
    }
```

Comment: what is your error?

Answer (score 1):

It may be occurring due to cucumbers packages is misconfigured. Check the GLUE options

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
          features = { "src/test/resources/features/CucumberTests.feature" }, 
          tags = { "@integration_test"},
          glue = { "br.com.cucumber.integration.stepDefinition" }, 
          format = { "pretty", "html:target/reports/cucumber/html", "json:target/cucumber.json", "usage:target/usage.jsonx", "junit:target/junit.xml" })
@ContextConfiguration(classes= AppConfiguration.class)
public class CumcumberTest extends BaseTestCase {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing as an "error" is in fact cucumber telling you that is not able to find the matching definition for the step "When Enter the Username and Password" and has auto-generated the example definition below based on the scenario outline data:

```
@When("^Enter the ADMIN and password(\\d+)$") 
public void enter_the_ADMIN_and_password(int arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

The problem is that your step definition is using quotes on the parameters but your actual step has no quotes, hence cucumber is not able to match them. You either need to change your step in the feature file to include quotes:

```
When Enter the "<Username>" and "<Password>"
```

Or you need to change the step definition to not include quotes:

```
@When("^Enter the (.*) and (.*)$")                  
public void enter_the_Username_and_Password(String username,String Password) throws Throwable                           
{       
   System.out.println("This step enter the Username and Password on the login page."+username +Password);
   loginObj.Login(driver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. For me the problem was that I created step definition in the package for back end tests instead of front end ones. If the step definition classes have same or similar names, it is possible to make a mistake. This would happen during chosing the wrong package while creating step definition from the feature file in Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue and discovered the reason was I accidentally gave the name of the class and not the package for the glue code:
The wrong argument value for my gluecode was my class as: gluecode="StepDefinition", when it should have been my package: gluecode="stepDefs"

My TestRunner.java looks as follows:

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features",
        glue = "stepDefs")

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. In my case I was forgetting the `.step.` part in my file name.

So I've solved by modifying my file name from:

`mystepfile.ts`

to:

`mystepfile.step.ts`